# Can't remove service "webdm"

Tags: uninstall, services

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 and I installed a service called `webdm` from the Software Center.

I tried to remove it but it hasn't been removed.

Comment: How did you try to remove it? Via the Software Center?

Comment: Yes , it kept saying " removing " and then nothing happened

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of the command `snap list`

Comment: I'm not going to submit this as an answer but you can run `sudo apt-get purge webdm`, enter your password, and enter `y` when you're prompted and that will either remove the program or give you some errors and give you some ideas of where to go next. Ping me with `@amolith` so I get a notification when you reply if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a lot of solutions but non of them worked
So i had to remove all the snapd / snappy packages 
Which i found here 
[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006164/cant-remove-service-webdm?noredirect=1#comment1628544_1006164)